# How to use events in Apex Charts vue

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, apexcharts

I'm new to apex charts and I'm trying to figure out how to properly use events(dataPointSelection) to display data from chart in the alert.  I'm using @click to call the method that fires alert but I would like to display series data in the alert.  Should I be using events something like this?

```
events:{ dataPointSelection:(event, chartContext, config)=>{} }
```

Here is a codepen

https://codepen.io/tone373/pen/poGZeVa?editors=1111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Vue's standard event handling syntax in the `<template>` like you're doing.
The parameters shown in the documentation are emitted to the event handlers in the template, you just have to add them to your function definition.

```html
<vue-apex-charts
  :type="chart.type"
  :height="chart.height"
  :options="chartOptions"
  :series="series"
  @click="selectBar"
/>
```

```js
selectBar(event, chartContext, config) {
  alert(`clicked ${this.series[0].data[config.dataPointIndex]}`);
}
```

[updated codepen](https://codepen.io/yoduh/pen/yLZqzdB?editors=1011)